# How to check if a variable is set in expect script?

Tags: tcl, expect

I am doing something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

if {$out != ""} {
  send_user $out
}
```

But it doesn't work. Error message:

```
can't read "out": no such variable
    while executing
"if {$out != ""} {
send_user $out
}"
    (file "./test" line 3)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The error you got is because of non-existence of the variable `out`.

To check variable's existence, use the following

```
if {[info exists out]} {
    puts "variable does exist"
}
```

`info exists` returns 1 if variable exist, else 0.

If variable exists, then you can use the code what you posted.

Comment: I think you mean `"variable does exist"` rather than `"variable does not exist"` :-)

Comment: For future readers, you may want to import variable from shell. So you have to use this too: `set out $env(out)`